# Were Hagar and Ishmael sent away two times?

Tags: genesis

We're Hagar and Ishmael sent away twice?

- Once when Hagar was pregnant with Ishmael (Gen 16) or when Israel was a baby,?
- Second time (Gen 21), were they sent away when he made fun of Isaac at Isaac's circumcision?

Comment: Welcome to BHSE. Thank you for your question. I edited a little. "We're"  is short  for  "we are". Do take the tour to see how this site works, unless you have already done so!

Comment: Short answer, Yes

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two theories about this question. The first follows the text and accepts there were two separate episodes. The second theory relies on [source criticism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_criticism_(biblical_studies)#) and concludes that these are two versions of what was once one story.

### Two Stories

Taking the literal approach, the first episode shows Hagar pregnant with Ishmael (Gen 16). However this story does not involve a "sending away." Rather, Hagar ran away on her own, because Sarah mistreated her. Neither Jacob nor Ishmael was born yet, based on the following:

> Then Sar′ai dealt harshly with her, and she fled from her. The angel
> of the Lord found her by a spring of water in the wilderness, the
> spring on the way to Shur... And the angel of the
> Lord said to her, “Behold, you are with child, and shall bear a son;
> you shall call his name Ish′mael, because the Lord has given heed to
> your affliction."

The second time (Gen 21), Hagar and Ishmael were sent away with God's approval after Ishmael mocked Isaac at the latter's circumcision feast. Thus, in one story Hagar leaves because she was mistreated by Abraham's primary wife; in the the second, she leaves because her son mistreated his younger half-brother.

### Two Versions of the Same Story

Source critics who accept the [Documentary Hypothesis](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Documentary_hypothesis), on the other, tend to see two versions of one story here. According to this theory, the first version comes from the  "J" source. The deity is called Yahweh (the Lord) and the primary wife is called Sarai. Hagar is mistreated and flees. The second version comes from a different source known as "E": the deity is now named Elohim and the primary wife is now called Sarah. Hagar's son is a potential threat and God insists they be sent into exile over Abraham's protest. In this theory, the stories were originally the same but evolved differently over many generations in the oral tradition until they were written down as two separate episodes and later incorporated into the Book of Genesis. This approach has been adopted by mainstream Christian scholars as well as skeptical critics. In its introduction to the Book of Genesis, [New American Bible](https://bible.usccb.org/bible/genesis/0), accepted by the Catholic Church in the USA, states:

> As far as the sources of Genesis are concerned, contemporary readers
> can reasonably assume that ancient traditions (J and E) were edited in
> the sixth or fifth century B.C. for a Jewish audience that had
> suffered the effects of the exile and was now largely living outside
> of Palestine.

**Conclusion: taking the text as written, it describes two different episodes. In the first, Hagar runs away when she is pregnant with Ishmael because Sarah/Sarai mistreated her. In the second, she is sent away after Isaac was born and Sarah (supported by God) insisted that Hagar and Ishmael should be sent into exile. An alternative hypothesis suggests the two stories originally described a single event but evolved into separate episodes.**

Answer (score 0):

You could be right, because there are references to Ishmael with Abram between the two episodes.

""Hagar bore Abram a son, and Abram called the name of his son whom Hagar bore Ishmael" Genesis ch16 v17 (RSV)

"And Abraham said to God 'O that Ishmael might live in thy sight" Genesis ch17 v18

"Then Abraham took Ishmael his son...And Ishmael his son was thirteen years old when he was circumcised in the flesh of his foreskin. That very day Abraham and his son Ishmael were circumcised" Genesis ch17 vv 23-26

Answer (score 0):

The extended story in Genesis about Abraham contains two instances of Hagar leaving Abraham's home:

**Genesis 16**

> V6 - But Abram said to Sarai, “Look, your slave woman is in your
> power; do to her what is good in your sight.” So Sarai treated her
> harshly, and she fled from her presence.

This was while Hagar was still pregnant, before the birth of Ishmael.  She then returned to Sarah and Abraham's home and gave birth to Ishmael.

**Genesis 21**

After the birth of Isaac, we have this recorded when Ishmael was at least 14 years old.

> **9** But Sarah saw that the son whom Hagar the Egyptian had borne to Abraham was mocking her son **10** and she said to Abraham, “Expel the
> slave woman and her son, for the slave woman’s son will never share in
> the inheritance with my son Isaac!”c
>
> **11** Now this matter distressed Abraham greatly because it concerned his son Ishmael. **12** But God said to Abraham, “Do not be distressed
> about the boy and your maidservant. Listen to everything that Sarah
> tells you, for through Isaac your offspring will be reckoned. **13**
> But I will also make a nation of the slave woman’s son, because he is
> your offspring.”
>
> **14** Early in the morning, Abraham got up, took bread and a skin of water, put them on Hagar’s shoulders, and sent her away with the boy.

**CONCLUSION**

There are two separate instance where Hagar left the home of Abraham:

- in the first case of her own volition, but then she returned to give birth to Ishamel
- In the second case, she and Ishmael left permanently at the instance of Sarah.